# Rails sunspot reindexing specific schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-solr, apartment-gem

I'm using rails-on-services/apartment this is a Multitenancy for Rails and ActiveRecord

my setup is every time I create a Tenant the gem automatically creates a specific schema for the new tenant.

every time I run the `rails sunspot:reindex` the record will not appear in the search level. but in `ActiveRecord`(ex.Client.all) the record is there.

my theory is the tenant I created is not reindexing. is there a way to reindex specific schema? or I'm missing something?

Comment: What version of rails & ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.6.5 & rails 6.0.4

Comment: It would help if you did a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is that when you run the rails `sunspot:reindex` command, the data for each tenant's schema isn't being reindexed. To fix this, you can create a custom Rake task that loops through each tenant and reindexes the data for each schema separately.

Follow these steps to create the Rake task:

1. Create a new file called `sunspot.rake` in your Rails project's `lib/tasks` directory:

   ```
   #lib/tasks/sunspot.rake

   namespace :sunspot do
     desc "Reindex all tenants"
     task reindex_tenants: :environment do
        all_tenants = Tenant.all
        all_tenants.each do |current_tenant|
         Apartment::Tenant.switch(current_tenant.schema_name) do
           puts "Reindexing schema: #{current_tenant.schema_name}"
           Rake::Task["sunspot:reindex"].execute
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```

This Rake task will iterate through all tenants, switch to the corresponding tenant's schema using `Apartment::Tenant.switch`, and then call the `sunspot:reindex` task to reindex the data for that schema.

2. To run the newly created Rake task, enter the following command:

   ```
   rake sunspot:reindex_tenants
   ```

This command will reindex the data for all tenants' schemas separately, ensuring that the data for each schema is indexed correctly.

Remember to replace `Tenant` with the appropriate model name that represents your tenant in your application.

Comment: thanks for the reply this helped to reindex all my tenants. unfortunately, the last tenant will be reindexed. will follow all the records of all my tenants.  for example, Tenant1 has 10 records for Table 1. then Tenant2 has 3 records for Table 1. when I reindex all. Tenant2 will be the last reindex. when I load the Tenant1 Table1 records will appear 3 records only.